# different output caused by concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency

```java
public class InstructionReorder {

    public int v1=1;
    public int v2=1;

    void foo() {
        v1 = v2+1;
        v2 = 0;
        System.out.println(String.format("%d and %d",v1,v2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final InstructionReorder ir = new InstructionReorder();
        for (int i=0;i<Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()>>2;i++) {
            new Thread(ir::foo).start();
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

The code got different outputs, sometimes got output1:

```
2 and 0
1 and 0
1 and 0
1 and 0
1 and 0
1 and 0
1 and 0
1 and 0
```

or sometimes got output2:

```
1 and 0
1 and 0
1 and 0
1 and 0
1 and 0
1 and 0
1 and 0
1 and 0
```

The output1 is the expected result. if I synchronized the method, I got output1 exactly,
but I don't want to use a lock.I tried volatile, but takes no effect.
How can I fix it without a lock?

Comment: You are starting multiple threads, and working with the same data from multiple threads, without any synchronization. In that case it's expected that the results become unpredictable. There is no way to get this reliably predictable without any kind of synchronization. This does not have anything to do with instruction reordering such as a compiler or a single processor core can do.

Comment: yes, i got it. The only "2 and 0" result maybe overwrite by other thread extractly before it was printed, then the output2 appears.. thanks alot.

Comment: Side note: `String.format("%d and %d",v1,v2)` is not better than `v1 + " and " + v2`. In fact, it’s less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you see is not related to instruction reordering but to concurrent access.
Have a look at "Java Concurrency in Practice" if you want to write correct multithreaded code in Java.

In short, all you need is a to use one synchronized block for v1 and v2 access.

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` won't help because it just guarantees that you access fields in a valid state.

'output2' comes from the next flow:

1. `Thread #1` does:

```
v1 = 1 + 1 = 2
v2 = 0
```

2. Then `Thread #2` comes to play before T1's print:

```
v1 = 0 + 1 = 1
v2 = 0
```

3. Then both print the same:

```
1 and 0
```

It's impossible to solve this without synchronization or locks. For example:

```
synchronized void foo() {
        v1 = v2+1;
        v2 = 0;
        System.out.println(String.format("%d and %d",v1,v2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need to use a lock. Apart from instruction reordering, the [Java Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) (JMM) and JVM/OS implementation details make the behaviour of your program undefined. I suggest to read up on the topic. For example by reading [Java concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_concurrency) on Wikipedia or the old, yet insightful book "[Java Concurrency in Practice](https://jcip.net/)".

Without a lock,<sup>(1)</sup> the [JMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) does not guarantee *visibility*: that other threads see the changes that you make to *v1* or *v2*. This can cause mayhem even without instruction reordering!
But even if visibility does work on your specific platform, there is no guarantee that the print line statement will be done in the correct order. Printing is I/O and likely a blocking operation. In that case, the scheduler or lock-implementation decides - fairly or unfairly - which thread gets to print first!

Therefore, there must be a lock around all access to *v1*, *v2*, and the print line statement.

### Why not use atomics without a lock?

Imagine that the correct values of *v1* and *v2* are important, *but the print order is not*.

In that case it is tempting to use only atomic variables, that ensure visibility between threads. However, managing more than one atomic variable correctly is complex. You might end up with number magic or your own lock implementation. Both are easy to get wrong, hard to debug, and the latter requires thorough knowledge of the [JMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) and [concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_concurrency).

In other words: use a lock, or synchronize `foo`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Using **synchronized** around the same scope is okay too.

Comment: In your specific use case and when printing order is not important, there is an atomic solution that is correct. But it only works because _v2_ always gets assigned zero. That is a rather synthetic use case. If I make it part of my answer, there is a danger that people copy that specific and limited solution to more general cases.